# How do i only get the date from string

Tags: c#, string

I have a small question.

I have to get only the Ship date "July 17, 2015" from the string. lets say this is my code:

```
 string result = "";
 foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
     if (el.GetAttribute("className") == "not-annotated hover")
     {
         result = el.InnerText;
         textBox2.Text = result;
     }
```

Now this is the output:

[image]

Comment: Could you show the complete html? It seems as if your div is an outer div, you need the one which displays the ship-date only. That would be the safest/easiest approach

Comment: What is the HTML you are testing?

Answer (score 1):

```
string result = "";
string date = "";
foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
    if (el.GetAttribute("className") == "not-annotated hover")
    {
        result = el.InnerText;
        date = Regex.Match(result , 
        String.Format(@"{0}\s(?<words>[\w\s]+)\s{1}", "Ship Date:", "Country:"),
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups["words"].Value;
        textBox2.Text = date ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if your div is an outer div, you need the one which displays the ship-date only. That would be the safest/easiest approach.

However, if all you have is that large string, you could split by new-line characters and get the date from the line which starts with `Ship date`:

```
string[] lines = result.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string dateString = lines
    .FirstOrDefault(l => l.Trim().StartsWith("Ship date", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

DateTime shipDate;
if (dateString != null)
{
    string[] formats = new[] { "MMMM dd, yyyy" };
    string datePart = dateString.Split(':').Last().Trim();
    bool validShipDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(
        datePart,
        formats,
        DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo,
        DateTimeStyles.None,
        out shipDate);

    if (validShipDate)
        Console.WriteLine(shipDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Output text that you have shared,

```
string result = "";
foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
    if (el.GetAttribute("className") == "not-annotated hover")
    {
        result = el.InnerText;
        if (result.IndexOf("Ship Date") == 0) //Ship Date text is present in the string
        {
            //since the string format is Ship Date: July 17, 2015 -
            //we can assume : as a delimiter and split the text
            string[] splitText = result.Split(':');
            string date = splitText[1].Trim(); //this will give the date portion alone
        }
        textBox2.Text = result;
   }
```

Hope this helps.

**NOTE:** This logic will work only if the *Ship Date* string in the HTML is received in the same format as specified in your [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mT6l.png) sample